# RST sequence number gap

Tags: tcp

I am analyzing the end of various TCP sessions and I am often observing the same pattern in case of a RST, the following being an exemplary session end (it's first sequence number, then acknowledgement number):

```
0890: 14:56:54.507349: <= 1997168101 1198807587  ACK,PSH - length: 00017
0891: 14:56:55.565251: <= 1997168101 1198807587  ACK,PSH - length: 00017
0892: 14:56:57.409887: => 1198807587 1997168118  ACK     - length: 00000
0893: 14:57:01.096632: => 1198807587 1997168118  ACK     - length: 01188
0894: 14:57:01.096645: <= 1997168118 1198808775  ACK     - length: 00000
0895: 15:00:32.390242: => 1198813327 1997168118  ACK,RST - length: 00000
0896: 15:00:32.390253: <= 1997168118 1198808775  ACK     - length: 00000
0897: 15:06:55.502604: <= 1997168118 1198808775  ACK,FIN - length: 00000
0898: 15:07:01.105218: <= 1997168118 1198808775  ACK,FIN - length: 00000
0899: 15:07:12.337226: <= 1997168118 1198808775  ACK,FIN - length: 00000
0900: 15:07:34.737225: <= 1997168118 1198808775  ACK,FIN - length: 00000
0901: 15:08:19.665225: <= 1997168118 1198808775  ACK,FIN - length: 00000
```

I am interested in the sequence number of the RST packet. I would expect 1198807587 + 1188 = 1198808775 as sequence number instead of 1198813327, i.e. there is a gap of 4552 bytes. I checked the complete session (packets 1-889) and made sure that this gap is real.

I am now wondering, what is the most likely explanation for this?

1. RST injection (with higher in-window sequence number)? I wouldn't think so, because the RST sender is gone completely immediately after sending the RST, so I assume it was actually himself sending the RST.
2. Packet loss? Seems valid to me. But I would assume that a deliberate RST by design would not cause any packet loss. Wrong assumption? What might cause a RST in case it is packet loss?
3. Any other explanations for the gap?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Blind Reset Attack Using the RST Bit" that is described in [RFC-5961](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5961#section-3).
But because the 'left side' is totally death after that (does not answers for those FIN-ACKs), the problem might be something else.

For example:

- Vulnerability scanner that check that the target follows the recommendation of RFC-5961 (sends challenge-ACK after such RST).